# Sync Framework 2.1 not completing sync

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using sync framework to sync datat from an Sql Server 2008 R2 database. when I run sync on my machine, from the installed wpf application or from visual studio, everything syncs properly.

The problem occurs when I install the program on another machine. It seems like the sync runs , when I look at the list of queries running in Sql Profiler, however the changes are not propergated to the sqlce data base.

Comment: Can you be little more specific. Where are databases located? Are you seeing the Sql Queiries coming up on Source and not on Destination? Is the new machine on which you are running WPF app having proper access to both source and destination DBs

Answer (score 0):

Trace what happens on the client. You'll probably see why the rows are not being inserted. See the following MSDN article [How to: Trace the Synchronization Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807160.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar problem:
We are using sync frame work to sync multiple site to central server. everything was working very well until the system producing the data was upgraded. now in some site i get insert errors, some about FK constraints and some about normal inserts trying to insert Nulls to non null-able columns.
from what i could find the _selectchanges SP is returning some non existing rows or with invalid data which then causes the errors in bulkinsert SP.

A workaround is to re-provision the scope and re-sync all data this straightens things out.

I'm trying to find the root cause so i can handle it re-syncing all data is not very good solution for us and not always possible.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Edit:
DBs schema is the same as before, only data is being changed.